# Redirect and Post Headers to another application Simultaneously - ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request, webclient, webrequest

I want to redirect a system to a centralized authentication server and I need to fill some parameters in headers and redirect to the authentication server completely. Using Web Client or Web Request I must return a value as a response to the requester ( They work as a listener ).

WebClient Send Request Example:

```
var values = new NameValueCollection();
values["clientId"] = clientId;
values["clientIP"] = currentIP;

byte[] response;
var resultResponse = string.Empty;

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    try {
            response = client.UploadValues(url, values);
            resultResponse = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
        }
    catch (WebException e)
        {
            string exception = string.Empty;
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                exception += ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
                exception += ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
            }
        }
    }
```

Web Request Example

```
string method = "post";
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.ContentType = contentType;
req.Method = method;            
req.Headers.Add("myhead", value);                  
req.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length;
var stream = req.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length);
stream.Close();
var response = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response);
var respo = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
response.Close();
return respo;
```

As you see in both methods the requester post the request and is waiting till receiving the response. I can not return to the requester system until I show two view to the user, get the username and passwords and finally process the information. I need to fill headers in a request, post it to the server and also redirect to the central authentication server. I searched a lot and found that it is impossible to post and redirect at a same time. Can you suggest any other methods to me?

Comment: Make your code Async or possibly introduce a proxy server

Comment: Your comment make no sense. please explain more if you can. thanks